# Plotting moving/rolling modal in R

Tags: r, plot, mode, moving-average

I have a set of data with multiple cases. Each case has a different number of observations. How can I calculate the moving modal and plot the moving modal? My current idea is to create lagging and leading data frames and then use `rowModes()` with base R to calculate the row modes but I am not sure how I would plot this.

For example, if I want to take the 7-day moving modal of `a` from the data below, how can I calculate the moving modal and plot it on a figure with `a` on the y-axis and `b`as dates on the x-axis?

```
a <- c(43,82,38,13,54,74,23,73,16,82,10,1,48,93,57,23,23,86,63,23,24,25,26,65,17,23,36,16,90,68,66)
b <- seq(as.Date("2010-12-01"), as.Date("2010-12-31"), by = "days")
testDF <- data.frame(a,b)
```

Comment: I don't see `rowModes()` function in base R anywhere. Also what is modal? How do you calculate it for one example? It would be helpful if you share your expected output for the data shared?

Comment: @RonakShah Modal is just mode which is the number that most frequently appears. In this case for the first 7 days (first 7 of  a, 43,82,...) all of the values appear the same amount so the mode I would plot would just be the average of those values.

Comment: So you mean if all the values appear same number of times you take their mean and if you have 7 values as 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2 you return 1?

Comment: Yes, exactly and I want to be able to shift the 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rolling functions available from the `zoo` package. If you want the output of 1-7 values at 7th place, 2-8 at 8th place and so on you can use :

```
library(zoo)

testDF$c <- as.numeric(rollapplyr(testDF$a, 7, function(x) {
  tab <- sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)
  if(length(unique(tab)) == 1) mean(x)
  else names(tab)[1]
}, fill = NA))
```

If you want the output of 1-7 values at 1st place, 2-8 at 2nd place and so on you can use :

```
testDF$c <- as.numeric(rollapply(testDF$a, 7, function(x) {
  tab <- sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)
  if(length(unique(tab)) == 1) mean(x)
  else names(tab)[1]
}, fill = NA, align = 'left'))
```